# tableviewercolumn setwidth percentages instead of pixels

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, swt, eclipse-rcp, tableviewer

the `setWidth` method for the `TableViewerColumn` class takes integer types, I would really like to use percentages, is there anyway to do this, or pack the table or something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `TableLayout` to layout your table and use `ColumnWeightData` to specify the 'weight' of each column.

For example, two columns with a 60 / 40 weighting:

```
TableViewer viewer = ....

TableLayout layout = new TableLayout();

TableViewerColumn col1 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);
layout.setColumnData(col1.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(60));

TableViewerColumn col2 = new TableViewerColumn(viewer, SWT.LEAD);
layout.setColumnData(col2.getColumn(), new ColumnWeightData(40));

viewer.getTable().setLayout(layout);
```

Comment: thank you! I have never used ColumnWeightData in a tablelayout before, it is a shame that window builder doesn't give me an option to do it through its interface.

Answer (score 1):

And yes, you can pack the table/tree too.

```
for (final TreeColumn item : tree.getColumns()) {
  item.pack();
}

for (final TableColumn item : table.getColumns()) {
  item.pack();
}
```

Which is quite similar to the CTRL+NUM-PAD '+' Keycode on Windows.